# Python minimalmodbus outputs ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, modbus

I wrote the following script to read modbus registers:

```
__author__ = 'oz'
import minimalmodbus
import serial

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 70)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.serial.timeout = 1.0
instrument.address = 70
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU

holdingunknown = instrument.read_register(40076, 1)

print holdingunknown
```

I get a value error as following:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/oz/PycharmProjects/untitled1/tst2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oz/PycharmProjects/untitled1/tst2.py", line 14, in <module>
    holdingunknown = instrument.read_register(40076, 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 254, in read_register
    return self._genericCommand(functioncode, registeraddress,    numberOfDecimals=numberOfDecimals, signed=signed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 693, in _genericCommand
    payloadFromSlave = self._performCommand(functioncode, payloadToSlave)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 794, in _performCommand
    payloadFromSlave = _extractPayload(response, self.address, self.mode, functioncode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/minimalmodbus.py", line 1054, in _extractPayload
    raise ValueError(text)
ValueError: Checksum error in rtu mode: '\x01d' instead of '\te' . The response is: 'F\x03    \x9c\x8c\x00\x01d' (plain response: 'F\x03\x9c\x8c\x00\x01d')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is this happening? the same happend to me when I switched mode to ASCII.
What can I change to get the response??

Comment: What's happening is that the instrument you're addressing is sending a wrong checksum, i.e, doesn't appear to be properly following the Modbus protocol.  A common problem, depending on the make and model of the instrument, see e.g http://www.control.com/thread/1026186143 etc etc.  What you can do about it mostly depends on the make and model of the instrument you're using, which you don't tell us, and how do you go about setting said instrument to proper Modbus operation!

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for answering. the product I use is a control box for smart-grid assets which uses rtu over tcp. this helps?

Comment: Unfortunately it can't help w/o knowing the exact make and model number, and even if I did know them I'm far too rusty on HW to help.  Rather, try electronics.stackexchange.com, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Almost definitively, the baudrate on your device is not 19200.  I had the same issue using Modbus-tk to simulate a modbusRTU slave, only to later discover that the sample code I was using initialized a serial port to a baud rate of 9600, rather than the default.  Fixing this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

reply  instrument is youhave written register address wrong.

write 0x0.1 to read first register. an modify  to read 0x1,1 to read second register or 0x0,8 to read 8 registers.need to understand how to write register values.